# How to view history of requests including usernames to HTML site with IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, http, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

I'm using an HTTP site to deploy an application to the people at my work. I'm using Windows Authentication and want to see a history of what users have made requests to the site in order to know who has installed the application.

Is there a way for me to view a history of requests that includes the username?

This is my first experience with IIS, so please correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the field `cs-username` selected to be logged and then check your IIS log file

This will point you to the area in IIS to check the logged fields and show you where the log is. 
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85